# Request.Form Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

```
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> keys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("NIpnD")).ToList();
        int i = 1;
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            this.AddPar(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

i have problem with this code that if i used a modal that not contains id with NIpnD i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object
have tried many if conditions to avoid this but without luck